# Does Icinga2 works with router between server and client

Tags: icinga2

I want to install an Icinga2 server in my home network and asking myself if this central instance is able to monitor also clients which are located outside anywhere in the internet, i.e. behind my router? I could imagine that the central instance is able to contact the outer client but is there a need for the outer client to contact the central instance by its own?

Comment: I think yes, for pulling the configuration from master.

Answer (score 0):

The connection has to be established, either from the central server, or from the client. If a client node *B.example.org* cannot contact the central server *A.example.org*, you can declare on the client *A.example.org* without any *Host* setting:

object Endpoint "A.example.org" {
}

So the node will know the topology, but will wait for an incoming connection.